# Which validation control to use when validating a variable in code behind (as opposed to another control)?

Tags: asp.net, validation-controls

Let's say I have a list of strings. I have a TextBox and a **ADD button** which adds no null values to the list.

There's also a **NEXT** button on the page. When the Next Button is clicked, the list's content is displayed on another page. I'd like to proceed to a Validation so that the user can get to the result page only if the list is not empty (contains at least one element).

Also, I'd like the error message to be displayed by a Summary Validation to keep a standard way of displaying errors. Here is the code I use to check which button was clicked and the number of elements in the list.

```
protected void UploadWizard_NextButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
{     
 string ctrlID = ObjectFinderHelpers.GetPostBackControl(this.Page).ID;
 if (ctrlID == "StepNextButton" & KeyWordList.Count == 0)
   //Do something to keep the user on the same page
   //So that he can add at least one element to the list 
 }
```

1. How do I proceed to the validation, i.e. which validation control do I need?
2. How do I display error message to a Summary Validation Control?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Customvalidatorcontrol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eee01cx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to do custom validation,implement the OnServerValidate to do custom validation. This can be integrated with the Validation Summary control as any standard validation control.

Comment: You are right. I tried the above code with a custom validation control as u suggested. It works. Thank you